# Angular singleton services shared between library and app

Tags: angular, singleton, angular-library

I am developing a library with some singleton services that should be used *both by the app that imports the library and by components in the library* as well.
What I've done:

1)Create a `CoreServicesModule` with the `forRoot` method. In the example the method takes an `environment` parameter which is used in some of these services.

```js
export class CoreServicesModule {
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule?: CoreServicesModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error('CoreServicesModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
    }

    public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders<CoreServicesModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: CoreServicesModule,
            providers: [
                BaseSingletonService,
                BaseSingletonService2,
                {
                    provide: 'environment',
                    useValue: environment
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

2)In the application I've injected the service in the component's constructor. I have **NOT** included the `CoreServicesModule` in my `LibraryComponentModule`, where this component is declared.

```js
import { BaseSingletonService } from "@myorg/library/src/library/services";
@Component({
  selector: "library-component",
  templateUrl: "./library-component.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./library-component.component.scss"],
})
export class LibraryComponent {
  constructor(private baseSingletonService: BaseSingletonService) {}
}
```

3)Imported the CoreServicesModule inside the application's app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      //...
    CoreServicesModule.forRoot(environment)
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Inside the application everything is working as expected. However when I use the `library-component` I get the `NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseSingletonService` error. What am I missing? How do you share singleton services between angular library and application?

Comment: If only one instance of service your want for both library and app.module.ts then , You can declare services as `@Injectable({providedIn : 'root'})` and then you do not need forRoot method to implement at all.

Comment: and one thing you can make your services injection in library component with @Optional() like this `export class LibraryComponent {
  constructor( @Optional() private baseSingletonService: BaseSingletonService) {}
}`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I need to use the forRoot because I need to pass the environment file from the app

Comment: Did you try @Optional() way as I have said to you in secod comment ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda yes, but it doesn't work (the service is assigned value null)

Comment: On way is You can provide coreServiceModule inside library main module too. Rather than provide it inside app.module.ts

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I don't have a main module in the library. Each component has its own.

Comment: You can still use @Injectable() with providedIn: root, and your core module has only one thing left is providing environment file,

Comment: If I do that (providedIn root and remove from coreServiceModule providers list) it gets instantied twice

Comment: No, ProvidedIn root is only instantiated once, as I know, But then you can also use providedIn : 'platform' too!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to

1. Do the `forRoot()` method **AND**
2. Declare the service with  `providedIn: 'platform'`

Just doing one of those without the other didn't seem to do it for me.

My other note is that it could be the order of the modules in your app.module.ts. If you import LibraryComponentModule before CoreServicesModule, the providers that LibraryComponentModule needs won't yet be provided.

Comment: So you provide the service inside the coremodule and than provide it again with scope "platform"? Are you sure it's not getting instantiated more than once?

Comment: Good point. Based on some logging the constructor is only ever called once. I don't feel comfortable with why providedIn: 'platform' doesn't seem to work by itself, seems to me like that is designed to be singleton no-matter-what, but from what I can tell this works for me.